# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I have this code, and all works well in my local server. The email is sent without any problem.

But now I pass the content to webserver, and I get this error...

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

SSL is enable in the server..correct? so, what is the problem?
[image]

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
            $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port
            $mail->Username   = "dnteiro"; // GMAIL username
            $mail->Password   = "xxx";      // GMAIL password
```

Comment: And your firewall allows outside connections to port 465?

Comment: the server that runs this php code.

Comment: great china firewall of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like your web host is blocking outbound connections to smtp.gmail.com:465.  Suggestions:

1. Verify:  If you have shell/terminal access to your web hosting server, try a telnet test **to verify that they are in fact blocking this**.  Run `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`
2. Contact:  Call or email your hosting provider and find out what SMTP server they provide for outbound relay.  Make sure they know you want to use your `@gmail.com` address as the From/Reply-to address.
3. Update code:  Once your host provides you with a different mail server, update your code and try again.

If your web host doesn't allow outbound relay from its servers at all, then  you need to look at switching hosts, if this is a requirement for your application.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, and telnet is actually working for me. So my host doesn't prevent me for reaching out to smtp.gmail.com through port 465. Any over suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

AJ is right in regards to #2, it is specified in:
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.abc.co.in';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
); 

$mail->Username = 'user name';
$mail->Password = 'password';

$mail->setFrom("from email id", "name");
$mail->addAddress("receipiant email id");

$mail->isHTML(true);
$bodycontent = 'body';
$mail->Body    = $bodycontent;

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "message has been not send", $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
else{
    echo "message has been send";
    }
```