# Error in sending email in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using following configuration for sending mail through php mail function :

```
function sendInvoiceEmail() {
```

GET CUSTOMER EMAIL

```
        $recieverEmail = xyz@test.com; //Valid Email ID
        $recieverName = xyz;
```

CREATE EMAIL CONFIGURATION ARRAY

```
    $emailConfig = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'abc@abc.com',   //Valid Email ID
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',      //Valid password
            'mailtype' => 'html', //text or html
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        );
```

Set your email information

```
        $from = array('email' => 'abc@abc.com', 'name' => 'Testing');

    $to = array('email' => $recieverEmail, 'name' => $recieverName);
        $subject = "Test Mail for Invoice ";

        $message = "Test Message for Invoice";
```

Load CodeIgniter Email library

```
        $this->load->library('email', $emailConfig);
        $this->email->initialize($emailConfig);
```

Sometimes you have to set the new line character for better result

```
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Set email preferences

```
        $this->email->from($from['email'], $from['name']);
        $this->email->to($to['email'], $to['name']);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
```

Ready to send email and check whether the email was successfully sent

```
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());                
        }
    }
```

I am having PHP 5.3.9 version and wampserver but I am getting following error :

```
An Error Was Encountered

The following SMTP error was encountered: 52770504 Unable to find the socket 
transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

data: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Thu, 27 Dec 2012 16:50:28 
+0530 From: "Invoice Tester" Return-Path: To: df@df.kl Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Test_Mail_for_Invoice_?= Reply-To: "sujit.singh@xpointers.com" X-Sender: sujit.singh@xpointers.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <50dc2efca4149@xpointers.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_50dc2efca4160" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_50dc2efca4160 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Test Message for Invoice --B_ALT_50dc2efca4160 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Test Message for Invoice --B_ALT_50dc2efca4160--
Unable to send data: .

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to
```

send mail using this method.

Comment: Please post what OS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know about wampserver there is setting in PHP Extension so if you are using wampserver then you can do the following step :

1) Go to WampSever Tray icon

2) Go to PHP Extension

3) Search for `php_openssl`

4) If it is not checked then mark  it as checked (`php_openssl`)

Otherwise you can refer Michael's answer :)

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the "smtp_host" to "**smtp.gmail.com**"

Check out: [SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209064/smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

**Try checking the SSL error:**

From the error it looks like your version of PHP might not have been compiled with ssl.

Run:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

And check if the "Configure Command" has something like "--with-openssl=/usr".
Also check that you have ssl listed in the "Registered Stream Socket Transports" section.

Comment: My Configure Command is showing like this : `cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-isapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"`

Comment: That might have been cut off. Did it have "ssl" in it? And can you tell me about the Registered Stream Socket Transports?

Comment: Sorry but How can I find out  : Registered Stream Socket Transports??

Comment: I got this in Registered Stream Socket Transports : tcp, udp, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls

Comment: OK, this means you have a bad url. Did you try changing the url of the smtp_host?

Comment: @YogeshPingle Did you get the same error message? And can you update the question to reflect the changed url.